# What are the differences between bitvectors and bitsets in c++?

Tags: c++

Are there any blatant differences between the two that makes one's use more practical in some situations than the other's?  Can someone please outline the differences here and any relevant performance information for both?

Comment: What do you mean by a bitvector (`std::vector<bool>` perhaps?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "bitvector," `std::vector< bool >`, is a dynamic-sized array on the heap, which satisfies most of the requirements for a Container class. To do so, it defines a funky `iterator` class which returns `reference` objects following the tricky proxy object design pattern.

A `std::bitset` is a static-sized array with the storage inline with the object. It doesn't have iterators, only access operators such as subscript.

The bitwise access part will perform similarly. The `vector` will also call `operator new` and `operator delete` when created and destroyed, and occasionally reallocate if necessary.